# Find middle element of a double linked list in constant time complexity

Tags: linked-list

I am trying to find the middle element of a double linked list in constant time complexity . 
I came across the following http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-a-stack-with-find-middle-operation/  solution.
But I don't understand how to use the middle pointer. 
Can anyone please help me understand this or give me a better solution .

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've re-written this code in C++ for explanation purposes:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef class Node* PNode;
class Node{
public:
    PNode next;
    PNode prev;
    int data;
    Node(){
        next = nullptr;
        prev = nullptr;
        data = 0;
    }
};

class List{
private:
    //Attributes
    PNode head;
    PNode mid;
    int count;
    //Methods
    void UpdateMiddle( bool _add );

public:
    //Constructors 
    List(){
        head = nullptr;
        mid = nullptr;
        count = 0;
    }
    ~List(){
        while( head != nullptr ){
            this->delmiddle();
            std::cout << count << std::endl;
        }
    }
    //Methods
    void push( int _data );
    void pop();
    int findmiddle();
    void delmiddle();
};

void List::UpdateMiddle( bool _add ){
    if( count == 0 ){
        mid = nullptr;
    }
    else if( count == 1 ){
        mid = head;
    }
    else{
        int remainder = count%2;
        if(_add){
            if( remainder == 0 ){
                mid = mid->prev;
            }
        }
        else{
            if( remainder == 1 ){
                mid = mid->next;
            }
        }
    }
}

void List::push( int _data ){
    PNode new_node = new Node();

    new_node->data = _data;
    new_node->prev = nullptr;
    new_node->next = head;

    if( head != nullptr ) head->prev = new_node;
    head = new_node;
    count++;

    UpdateMiddle( true );
}

void List::pop(){
    if( head != nullptr ){
        PNode del_node = head;
        head = head->next; 

        if( head != nullptr ) head->prev = nullptr;

        delete del_node;
        count--;
        UpdateMiddle(false);
    }
    else if( count != 0 ){
        std::cout << "ERROR";
        return;
    }
}

int List::findmiddle(){
    if( count > 0 ) return mid->data;
    else return -1;
}

void List::delmiddle(){
    if( mid != nullptr ){
        if( count == 1 || count == 2){
            this->pop();
        }
        else{
            PNode del_mid = mid;
            int remainder = count%2;

            if( remainder == 0 ){
                mid = del_mid->next;
                mid->prev = del_mid->prev;
                del_mid->prev->next = mid;
                delete del_mid;
                count--;
            }
            else{
                mid = del_mid->prev;
                mid->next = del_mid->next;
                del_mid->next->prev = mid;
                delete del_mid;
                count--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The push and pop functions are self-explanatory, they add nodes on top of the stack and delete the node on the top. In this code, the function `UpdateMiddle` is in charge of managing the `mid` pointer whenever a node is added or deleted. Its parameter `_add` tells it whether a node has been added or deleted. This info is important when there is more than two nodes.

Note that when the `UpdateMiddle` is called within `push` or `pop`, the counter has already been increased or decreased respectively. Let's start with the base case, where there is 0 nodes. `mid` will simply be a `nullptr`. When there is one node, `mid` will be that one node.

Now let's take the list of numbers "5,4,3,2,1". Currently the mid is 3 and `count`, the amount of nodes, is 5 an odd number. Let's add a 6. It will now be "6,5,4,3,2,1" and `count` will now be 6 an even number. The `mid` should also now be 4, as it is the first in the middle, but it still hasn't updated. However, now if we add 7 it will be "7,6,5,4,3,2,1", the `count` will be 7, an odd number, but notice that the `mid` wont change, it should still be 4.

A pattern can be observed from this. When adding a node, and `count` changes from even to odd, the `mid` stays the same, but from odd to even `mid` changes position. More specifically, it moves one position to the left. That is basically what `UpdateMiddle` does. By checking whether `count` is currently odd or even after adding or deleting a node, it decides if `mid` should be repositioned or not. It is also important to tell whether a node is added or deleted because the logic works in reverse to adding when deleting. This is basically the logic that is being applied in the code you linked.

This algorith works because the position of `mid` should be correct at all times before adding or deleting, and function `UpdateMiddle` assumes that the only changes were the addition or deletion of a node, and that prior to this addition or deletion the position of mid was correct. However, we make sure of this by making the attributes and our function `UpdateMiddle` private, and making it modifiable through the public functions.

Comment: Hi, this code have a error in the function UpdateMiddle, not work correctly, the code stops working and closes execution

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that you don't *find* it via a search, rather you constantly maintain it as a property of the list. In your link, they define a structure that contains the head node, the middle node, and the number of nodes; since the middle node is a *property* of the structure, you can return it by simply accessing it directly at any time. From there, the trick is to maintain it: so the `push` and `pop` functions have to adjust the middle node, which is also shown in the code.

More depth: maintaining the middle node: we know given the count that for an odd number of nodes (say 9), the middle node is "number of nodes divided by 2 rounded up," so 9/2 = 4.5 rounded up = the 5th node. So if you start with a list of 8 nodes, and add a node, the new count is 9, and you'll need to shift the middle node to the "next" node.  That is what they are doing when they check if the new count is even.